# unable to check onepagecheckout is enabled or not in prestashop

Tags: payment-gateway, prestashop

I am using `prestashop 1.5.3` and i am developing a payment gateway problem is this i couldn't find how to check onepage checkout is enabled or not please help to check this because my payment gateway is working good on step by step payment gateway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check it easily. If you mean at admin, then go to admin control panel, click on

**Preferences -> Orders**  and there find out **Order process type** . There if **One page checkout** is selected, then it is enabled, else not.

Programmatically you can find it as below :

```
if(Configuration::get('PS_ORDER_PROCESS_TYPE') == 1)
 //one page checkout is enabled
```

If PS_ORDER_PROCESS_TYPE is one, then one page checkout is enabled, else not.

Comment: can you please check my second problem @altafhussain  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17402143/how-to-select-carrier-option-programmatically-in-prestashop